# why cakepdf isnot rendering css?

Tags: pdf-generation, cakephp-2.1, dompdf

I am generating pdf using cakepdf but it is not rendering included css though `'fullbase' => true` is specified. 
Same for images, Even though full base path is specified, it can't load image. 
I have to write internal css.
 
Any help would be appriciated.

Comment: Have you set DOMPDF_ENABLE_REMOTE to true?

Comment: yes i have added that.. still not working

Comment: Do you get any PHP errors? Can you share a sample of the URL for the CSS?

Comment: Hi there! I'm having the same issue with CSS on CakePdf. Did you have a solution to this problem? @Amss